# Getting a random sample of a list in F#

Tags: f#

I am writing some code in F# and I need a random sample from a list. Something similar to the Python [Random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is exactly what I am looking for.

```ml
let sample count list = ?

let list = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6 ]

sample 3 list |> List.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x)
```

Should output something like:

```
[2; 4; 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let sample count (xs: _ list) = [for i in 1 .. count -> xs[System.Random.Shared.Next() % xs.Length]]
```

or

```
let sample count (xs: _ list) = List.init count (fun _ -> xs[System.Random.Shared.Next() % xs.Length])
```

Comment: Wouldn't that sample duplicates?

Comment: Which, afaik, is what Python Random.choice does ("with replacement").

Comment: In the end I made it work with https://fsprojects.github.io/FsRandom/reference/fsrandom-arraymodule.html, but this is much better since you don't need one more dependency and FsRandom is probably overkill for this.

Comment: Could you also explain the difference between the two and how they approximately work? As I understand it now, the first is a variable and the second is a function.

Comment: Both are function definitions. The right hand side (to the right of the equal sign) is in both cases an expression. In the first case it is a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), described for F# sequences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences#sequence-expressions), but working similarly for lists. The second case just uses the `List.init` function which is documented [here](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html).

Comment: The second argument to the init function is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/lambda-expressions-the-fun-keyword).